# Pandas: find nearest higher high (OHLC)

Tags: python, pandas, ohlc

I'm trying to find the fastest solution to iterate over each row of Open High Low Close data and count out how many rows exist between the current row's high and the next high that’s greater than or equal to the original.  Here is a shortened code example which I think explains it well (I'd be trying to find the final value of `_next`):

```
for i in df.index:
    while df.loc[i, 'high'] > df.loc[_next, 'high']:
         _next += 1
```

I think I need to use a `lambda` function inside `apply` but I can't seem to get it right.  Been trying to figure this out for days and would love any advice!

Using this data, the function should return `[2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0]`

```
d = {'high': [1.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


    high   rows_to_higher_high
0   1.2    2
1   1.1    0
2   1.1    0
3   1.4    3
4   1.3    1
5   1.2    0
6   1.3    0
```

Edit: itertuples(name=None, index=True) is the fastest way to do it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `list comprehension`  and get `index to list`

```
In [166]: d = {'high': [1.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3]}

In [167]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

In [168]: df['rows_to_higher_high']=[(df['high'].values[i+1:]>=val).tolist().index(True) if True in (df['high'].values[i+1:]>=val).tolist() else le
     ...: n((df['high'].values[i+1:]>=val).tolist())  for i, val in enumerate(df['high'].values)]

In [169]: df
Out[169]:
   high  rows_to_higher_high
0   1.2                    2
1   1.1                    0
2   1.1                    0
3   1.4                    3
4   1.3                    1
5   1.2                    0
6   1.3                    0
```

Comment: Thank you Akhilesh, that worked.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be a huge improvement over the simple loop I posted in the first example

Answer (score 0):

Base on my understanding, we can get the subtraction from current row by all value, then get the upper tri , and get the index max with `argmax` when the value is more than 0

Sample :

```
s
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    3
4    1
5    1
6    5
dtype: int64
```

Solution :

```
np.clip(np.triu((s.values-s.values[:,None])>0,0).argmax(1)-np.arange(len(s)),a_min=0, a_max=None)
array([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

Comment: That is mind numbing, however not what I'm trying to do. I've made an addendum to the post to add in data.