# Python find higher high's

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the date and price of the next highest high in a pandas dataframe.

example dataframe:

```
       Date  Price
   20200501    1.5
   20200502    1.2
   20200503    1.3
   20200504    1.4
   20200505    1.2
   20200506    1.1
   20200507    1.3
```

let's say on 20200508 the high is 1.15. How can I retreive the following output from this dataframe?

```
       Date  Price
   20200501    1.5
   20200504    1.4
   20200507    1.3
```

example dataframe code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [20200501, 20200502, 20200503, 20200504, 20200505, 20200506, 20200507], 'Price': [1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.2, 1.1, 1.3]})

print(df)
```

hope this explains the problem briefly and clearly enough.

EDIT:
This thread might explain my problem more clearly enough, altough the author requires a different solution. [Pandas: find nearest higher high (OHLC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963977/pandas-find-nearest-higher-high-ohlc)

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. You want to sort your dataframe by price?

Comment: I want to find the higher high's. so 1.15 is the current price, and I want to know what the next higher highs are. so 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5 in this case. meaby I should create a different dataframe to make it more clear?

Comment: Updated my post and linked to a thread from someone with a similar problem, but he required a different solution and I can't wrap my head around how i can morphe that to fix my issue

Comment: Why not 1.2 in 20200502 , before 1.3 ?

Comment: Because 1.3 is higher than 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your sample, you may try this way

```
df[df.Price[::-1].cummax().eq(df.Price)]

Out[21]:
       Date  Price
0  20200501    1.5
3  20200504    1.4
6  20200507    1.3
```

Comment: This is absolutely beautifull and works like a charm! exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Jackey12345: great! happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks! Happy solving!